# Finding if a property inside a list inside a list doesnt contain a specific string

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a huge product database im working with threw a api

The API returns a Product those Products have MetaData which are stuff like minQuantities Maxes ect

Now I noticed some products dont have "variation_maximum_allowed_quantity" or " maximum_allowed_quantity"

So for every Product I have to look threw That Products meta data to so something like

```
 foreach (var item in VarProduct)
 {
   foreach (var metaItem in item.meta_data)
    {

    }

 }
```

The issue is meta_data have Key's Id's and value's I need to check against every key inside of every meta_data inside of every Product if that makes sense? Im wrecking my brain atm, Anyone know how I can check against all of those to see if those 2 Strings are missing? I need to be able to do something like

```
if(mdDoesntcontain)
{ 
 //This means stock is Unlimiteed so need to set a value for stock
   item.stockquantity = 9999999; (or int.maxValue())
}
```

Little tricky Posting this as a Block but:

```
-item.meta_data count = w.e
 -[0]
   -base
     -id = 101231
     -key = "min_max_rules"
     -value = "no"

 -[1]
   -base
     -id = 123131
     -key = "variation_minimum_allowed_quantity"
     -value = ""(this means 1 usually)
```

```
public class MetaData
{
    private object preValue;

    [DataMember (EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public int? id {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [DataMember (EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string key {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [DataMember (EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public object value {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

Comment: We don't know what your `meta_data` looks like, so how can we help?

Comment: I just realized that will post a CodeBlock of it in 2 seconds apps building

Comment: do NOT post code as images

Comment: - some products dont have "variation_maximum_allowed_quantity"  - do you mean there are no such property sometimes or it's empty?

Comment: Why on earth is `value` equal to `""`? This means 1 **usually**? If it means 1, why isn't it 1? Seems like a terrible API to me.

Comment: There are a property like that most of the time if that property's value is empty that means unlimited, But if it the property and key all together just doesn't exists that also means its unlimited

Comment: @ThePerplexedOne I 10000% agree with you, But its what im stuck working with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach (var item in VarProduct)
{
    hasQuantity = false;
    foreach (var metaItem in item.meta_data)
    {
        if (metaItem.id == "variation_maximum_allowed_quantity" || metaItem.id == "maximum_allowed_quantity") {
            hasQuantity = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!hasQuantity) {
        item.stockQuantity = int.MaxValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this be the solution you're looking for?

```
foreach (var item in VarProduct)
{
    var hasQuantity = false;
    foreach (var metaItem in item.meta_data)
    {
        if (metaItem.key == "variation_maximum_allowed_quantity" || metaItem.key == "maximum_allowed_quantity") {
            item.stockQuantity = metaItem.value == "" ? 1 : int.Parse(metaItem.value);
            hasQuantity = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!hasQuantity) {
        item.stockQuantity = int.MaxValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use linq Any operation:

```
foreach (var item in VarProduct) 
{
    if (!item.meta_data.Any(m => m.key.Equals("variation_maximum_allowed_quantity") 
        || m.key.Equals("maximum_allowed_quantity")))
    {
        item.stockQuantity = int.MaxValue;
    }
}
```